# Windows Script Host Error 0x800700C1 Code 800700C1

Tags: c++, vbscript, mfc, wsh, ole-automation

I was reading chapter 20 "Automation" of the book by Jeff Prosise "Programming Windows with MFC", 2nd ed. There are instructions on how to create a small automation server with methods `long Add(long, long)`, `long Subtract(long, long)`, and a property `double Pi`. There's also a script in VBScript to test that server. When I ran that script the message box with error 0x800700c1 was shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the file `\Documents` in my system drive (where Windows is installed). The automation server was in one of `\Documents and Settings` subfolders of the same drive. After deleting `\Documents` file everything ran fine. I currently don't know which application created that file.